# Access command line argument inside bash function?

Tags: bash, function, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to access a command line argument within the function below but I can't get it to work.  I believe it has something to do with the quotes but I can't figure it out.

```
search_second_line() {
    awk 'FNR==2 {if (/$1)/) print FILENAME; nextfile}' ./*
}
alias st="search_second_line"
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your sample input/output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work (but you have to be careful what you use for an argument):

```
st() { awk "FNR==2 {if (/$1/) print FILENAME; nextfile}" ./*; }
```

The danger here is that `$1` becomes part of the code and, if it includes awk-active characters, could do surprising things.

This is a bit safer:

```
st() { awk -v c="$1" 'FNR==2 {if ($0 ~ c) print FILENAME; nextfile}' ./*; }
```

Here, we pass into awk a variable `c` that has the contents of `$1`.  awk will know to treat `c` as a variable, not as code.

This is the same as the above but it simplifies the logic:

```
st() { awk -v c="$1" 'FNR==2 && $0~c {print FILENAME; nextfile}' ./*; }
```

#### How it works

- `-v c="$1"`

  This defines awk variable `c`.  This is the most reliable to pass information from the shell to `awk`.
- `FNR==2 && $0~c {print FILENAME; nextfile}`

  This applies two conditions and'd together before the `print`/`nextfile` statement is executed.  The first requires that this be the second line.  The second requires that this line match `c`.

#### The shell and quoting

The difference between single and double quotes is easily demonstrated at the command line.  Try:

```
$ var="Hello"
$ echo '$var'
$var
$ echo "$var"
Hello
```

As shown above, the shell treats the contents of single-quotes literally.  It makes no changes to what is inside single-quotes.  By contrast, the shell will process the contents of double-quotes, doing variable substitution (shown above), as well as command substitution and arithmetic expansion.  To demonstrate the latter two:

```
$ echo '$var $(date) $((2*3))'
$var $(date) $((2*3))
$ echo "$var $(date) $((2*3))"
Hello Wed Nov 19 14:15:44 PST 2014 6
```

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%q\n'` rather than `echo` for your demonstrations -- that way the effects of string-splitting will be obvious, too, distinguishing `printf '%q\n' $var $(date) $((2*3))` from `printf '%q\n' "$var" "$(date)" $((2*3))`.