# Access positional parameters from within a function in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a bash script file, is there a way that I can use command line arguments from within a function which has parameters?

Or do I need to assign all command line parameters to a variable for them to be accessible in the function body?

```sh
echo $1   # may be "abc"

function f() { $1; }   # will be "def", but I need "abc" here

f "def"
```

---

PS: I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027847/access-command-line-argument-inside-bash-function) on stack overflow, but that question doesn't deal with the issue I describe here?

Comment: Just use `f "$1"`

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a way to access the script-level command line arguments from within a shell function.  The meanings of `$1`, `$@` and `$*` are overridden in the function by the function's context.  You could create an array outside the function containing the command-line arguments – `args=("$@")` — and reference that within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, this is possible in [`extdebug`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) mode through [`BASH_ARGC`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fARGC) and [`BASH_ARGV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fARGV) variables, but populating a global array with positional parameters is much easier than that, and has no side-effects.

```
$ bash -O extdebug -s foo bar
$ f() {
>   declare -p BASH_ARGC BASH_ARGV
>   echo ${BASH_ARGV[BASH_ARGC[0] + BASH_ARGC[1] - 1]}
> }
$ f 42 69
declare -a BASH_ARGC=([0]="2" [1]="2")
declare -a BASH_ARGV=([0]="69" [1]="42" [2]="bar" [3]="foo")
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
SCRIPT_ARG=$1

function f() { 
  FUNC_ARG=$1; 

  echo $SCRIPT_ARG # Prints "abc"
  echo $FUNC_ARG   # Prints "def"

}

f "def"
```